# A Variable changing the output

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

So i just run a quick example and could use some help understanding what happend

I run the test with the Variable "RandomNumber" commented and the output was

```
Construct
Invoke
Destruct
```

So I run the test again but with the Variable "RandomNumber" uncommented and the output was

```
Construct
Destruct
Invoke
```

I tried that many times with the same result but i don't really understand why that Variable is changing the lifetime of the Tester... 
The Test:

```
struct Container 
{
    template<typename T>
    Container(T&& O) : Data((void*)std::addressof(O)) {}

private:
    void* Data;
    //std::weak_ptr<int> RandomNumber;
};

struct Tester
{
    Tester() { std::cout << "Construct" << std::endl; }
    ~Tester() { std::cout << "Destruct" << std::endl; }
};

void TestFunction1(const std::vector<Container>& Data)
{
    std::cout << "Invoke" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    TestFunction1({ Tester() });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since both orders are valid, why does it matter?

Comment: The reason why it is happening is that you don't use Data anywhere so the compiler can do what it likes - it might (with some optimisations turned on) even be able to elide the construction all together.  Different compilers with different optimizers will be different - so you are seeing that behaviour and I am not.  So I either have a different compiler or different optimisation flags. 
 Predicting what a compiler optimiser will do it impossible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the code multiple times on Windows 10, I have observed that it produces almost the same output whether `weak_ptr<int> RandomNumber` is commented or not:

```
Construct
Invoke
Destruct
```

This implies that output differs in systems as other online compilers have produced the same result as you. The most probable reason is the output is system/compiler dependent and the different optimizations the compiler does.

Answer (score 1):

After testing on multiple configurations the result varies from system to system and compiler to compiler. Hence, it is difficult to predict what the outcome could be.